# Why this token is not available in this context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a context as like this

```
import { JamService } from '@healint/jam-service-wrapper';

export const jamService = new JamService(
   env.jamServiceUrl
 );

export const JamContext =
  createContext<JamService>(jamService);
export const useJamService = (): JamService => {
  const authToken = useAuthToken();
  const service = useContext(JamContext);
  if (authToken) {
    service.token = authToken;
  }
  return service;
};
```

But in the `if` statement `service.token` is giving me this error. I don't know why this is giving me error when I already declare a `token` in jamService

```
Property 'token' does not exist on type 'JamService'.
```

JamService FILE

```
    export class JamService extends BaseService {
      BASE_URL = '/jams/';
      constructor(token: string) {
        super(token);
      }
  
      public async findUserjam(){

      }

   }
```

Comment: You've not declared `token` in `JamService`. It's only a constructor parameter. It's not a property.

Comment: @VLAZ I am new to class component. Can you elaborate

Comment: There is no field `token` in the JamService class. Therefore, it's not "declared" in JamService. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html

Comment: `token` is a parameter in the constructor but not a property of that class